# When Bot is hosted on Azure, I'm unable to retrieve values from Adaptive card in waterfall dialog inside validator method

Tags: botframework, adaptive-cards

I'm using **Adaptive card version 1.2** and **Bot Builder dialog version is 4.5.1** in my Bot. Currently I'm calling adaptive card inside waterfall dialog using `TextPrompt`. I have written a validator method to validate values returned from the card. This works fine in Bot Emulator. But when I host it on Azure I'm Getting error.

In the validator method, Adaptive card values are captured in `promptContext.Recognized.Value`. But it returns `null` when hosted on Azure which results in *Object reference not set to an instance of an object* exception.

```cs
//DialogClass
 AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(nameof(WaterfallDialog), new WaterfallStep[]
 {
      AdaptiveCardAsync,            
  }));
  AddDialog(new TextPrompt("AdaptiveCard", CardValidator));


private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SelectedOptionAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
                    // Get Adaptive Card
                    JObject card = AdaptiveCard();

                    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("AdaptiveCard",
                    new PromptOptions
                    {
                        Prompt = (Activity)MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment
                        {
                            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                            Content = card,
                        }),
                    }, cancellationToken);
}


//Calling adaptive card. 
 public JObject AdaptiveCard()
 {
      string fileName = "GetValues.json";
      // combine path for cross platform support
      string[] paths = { ".", "AdaptiveCards", fileName };
      string fullPath = Path.Combine(paths);
      var adaptiveCard = File.ReadAllText(fullPath);
      JObject card = JObject.Parse(adaptiveCard);
}   

// To validate values received from adaptive card.
 private async Task<bool> CardValidator(PromptValidatorContext<string> promptContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{

var result =  JObject.Parse(promptContext.Recognized.Value);

}  


//Calling Dialog - DialogExtension.cs
 public static class DialogExtension
    {
        public static async Task Run(this Dialog dialog, ITurnContext turnContext, IStatePropertyAccessor<DialogState> accessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            try
            {
                var dialogSet = new DialogSet(accessor);
                dialogSet.Add(dialog);

                var dialogContext = await dialogSet.CreateContextAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
                // Ensure that message is a postBack (like a submission from Adaptive Cards)
                if (dialogContext.Context.Activity.GetType().GetProperty("ChannelData") != null)
                {
                    var channelData = JObject.Parse(dialogContext.Context.Activity.ChannelData.ToString());
                    if (channelData.ContainsKey("postBack") || channelData.ContainsKey("postback"))
                    {
                        var postbackActivity = dialogContext.Context.Activity;
                        // Convert the user's Adaptive Card input into the input of a Text Prompt
                        // Must be sent as a string
                        postbackActivity.Text = postbackActivity.Value.ToString();
                        //await dialogContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(postbackActivity);
                    }
                }
                var results = await dialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(cancellationToken);
                if (results.Status == DialogTurnStatus.Empty)
                {
                    await dialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(dialog.Id, null, cancellationToken);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
               await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(MessageFactory.Text(ex.Message));
            }
        }
```

Kindly help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: When testing your deployed bot, are you using "Test in Web Chat"? That uses V3 of WebChat (soon upgrading to V4) and V3 doesn't work with Adaptive Cards.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Yes..Tested in "Test in Web Chat" and also used WebChat URL. Can you please suggest the solution.

Comment: @mdrichardson-MSFT Today again I encountered similar issue, Into my Bot I have integrated LUIS( Version 4.5) It's working fine in emulator. When hosted it's not getting connected to LUIS. Is this also because of Web Chat Version.

Comment: Regarding Web Chat: If you used the embed iFrame for testing, that one also uses V3 of WebChat (for now...in process of upgrading). So that would explain that issue. For LUIS, check to make sure your LUIS settings from `appsettings.json` are also in `Azure Portal > Resource Group > App Service > Configuration`

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to @.mention you and wanted to make sure you got the notification.

Comment: @mdrichardson correct me if im wrong, but if we make any changes in Azure for LUIS won't it affect the other v4 projects? And also any details on when can we expect Web Chat new version

Comment: I'll add an answer that's a little more specific.

Comment: Thank you..that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that both "Test in Web Chat" and the Web Chat iFrame `<embed>` code still uses WebChat V3, which doesn't support Adaptive Cards well. WebChat V4 should be rolling out to both of those in the next couple of weeks.

Regarding your LUIS issue, go to:

1. Azure Portal
2. Your Resource Group
3. Your App Service that Your Bot Uses

[image]

4. Go to Configuration

[image]

5. Ensure that all of your config values match the ones in your `appsettings.json` file.

This will not affect your other V4 bots since each bot *should* use its own App Service.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned method for LUIS but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @Gags08 Can you include your Adaptive Card JSON? DirecLine Connector (which Web Chat uses) only supports Adaptive Cards v1.06, currently. If your card includes other elements, it may be causing issues. There are [some workarounds](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Services/issues/87#issuecomment-500662897), however.

Comment: Currently I'm waiting for Web Chat new release as v3 in Web Chat doesn't support Adaptive cards v1.2.

Comment: But the solution you have mentioned regarding LUIS issue didn't work for me. Could you suggest any other solution. And also when  can we expect new Web Chat release? I have put a hold to publish them in Azure.

Comment: @Gags08 I can't imagine anything else that would cause LUIS to not work when deployed, but is working locally. As this is a separate issue that needs more detail, please open a new StackOverflow question with details and error messages. No ETA on when Web Chat will support Adaptive Cards v1.2. I recommend not using features from 1.2 or using the workaround posted above.